# MultiThread issue about waiting for the same NSCondition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If there are 3+ threads with different priorities waiting for the same NSCondition, when this NSCondition invoke -(void)signal, do they have the same chance to be waked, or the highest priority thread will be most likely waked?

In another way to say this, is the priority of thread will affect when they be signaled?

Sorry for my bad english, hah

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it depends on the order of calling "wait", only. The thread calling "wait" first will be waked up first when the condition is signaled. And thread's priority doesn't change any thing at all. I guess there is a queue containing all the thread waiting the condition and the order of deque decides everything.